# org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException [Company.Table#-1]

Tags: sql, hibernate, gwt

I set up a new database on 2 new servers and got this error in my GWT application on both servers:

```
Fatal Error:
org.orm.PersistentException: org.orm.PersistentException:
org.orm.PersistentException: 
org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [Company.Table#-1]
```

The same system is already running on 5 other servers without problems (same MS SQL version, same GWT application, sql data is replicated). Therefore, I think it is not a bug in my GWT application.

Answer (score 0):

The same error I used to get. I found that the data is already deleted or not available in database but still data was accessed from eg: from client.
ex. I deleted one row from from my view GRID in GWT App but it was not reloaded and it was showing on screen I again tried to delete the same row I got this error.

Solution : Refresh the page will solve the problem. It worked for me. :)